# use of “have more distance” in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "have more distance" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? Is the following sentences correct grammatically?If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> also, center of leakage vortex for variable thickness blade have more
>   distance from the suction surface than constant thickness
>   blade(approximately two times more).

[image]
[image]

Comment: "[...] blade **is** farther/further from [...]" (unless there are several blades).

Comment: The blade not, vortex is farther..The blade is fix

Comment: Yes, my bad. You are missing a whole bunch of "the" though.

Comment: "also, center of leakage vortex for variable thickness blade is farther from the suction surface than constant thickness blade(approximately two times more). " Is it OK?

Comment: "also, **the** center of **the** leakage vortex for **the** variable thickness blade is farther from the suction surface than **the** constant thickness blade (approximately **twice the distance** (or **two times farther**)). You can also go with "is at a greater distance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though consider "a greater distance" in place of "more distance". You have, however, another problem: "Center" is singular (and has no definite article; "the"), but the verb "have" is not third person singular.

There are also some words that could be pluralised, depending on context. Thus I'd suggest:

> also, **the** center of **the** leakage vortex for variable thickness blade**s** **has** **greater** distance from the suction surface than constant thickness blade**s** (approximately two times more).